# Downloading the entire Bitcoin transaction chain with R

Tags: r, bitcoin

I'm pretty new here so thank you in advance for the help. I'm trying to do some analysis of the entire Bitcoin transaction chain. In order to do that, I'm trying to create 2 tables

1) A full list of all Bitcoin addresses and their balance, i.e.,:

```
| ID | Address     | Balance  |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 7d4kExk...  | 32       |
| 2  | 9Eckjes...  | 0        |
| .  | ...         | ...      |
```

2) A record of the number of transactions that have ever occurred between any two addresses in the Bitcoin network

```
| ID | Sender      | Receiver      | Transactions |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 7d4kExk...  | klDk39D...    | 2            |
| 2  | 9Eckjes...  | 7d4kExk...    | 3            |
| .  | ...         | ...           | ..           |
```

To do this I've written a (probably very inefficient) script in R that loops through every block and scrapes blockexplorer.com to compile the tables. I've tried running it a couple of times so far but I'm running into two main issues

1 - It's very slow... I can imagine it's going to take at least a week at the rate that it's going

2 - I haven't been able to run it for more than a day or two without it hanging. It seems to just freeze RStudio.

I'd really appreaciate your help in two areas:

1 - Is there a better way to do this in R to make the code run significantly faster?

2 - Should I stop using R altogether for this and try a different approach?

Thanks in advance for the help! Please see below for the relevant chunks of code I'm using

```
url_start <- "http://blockexplorer.com/b/"
url_end <- ""

readUrl <- function(url) {  
  table <- try(readHTMLTable(url)[[1]])
  if(inherits(table,"try-error")){
    message(paste("URL does not seem to exist:", url))
    errors <- errors + 1
    return(NA)
  } else {
    processed <- processed + 1
    return(table)
  }

}

block_loop <- function (end, start = 0) {

...

  addr_row <- 1 #starting row to fill out table
  links_row <- 1 #starting row to fill out table      

  for (i in start:end) {
    print(paste0("Reading block: ",i))
    url <- paste(url_start,i,url_end, sep = "")
    table <- readUrl(url)

    if(is.na(table)){ next } 

....
```

Comment: Please update the question with your R code; otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot, but just posted it

Comment: Could you perhaps clean up the code you posted? Right now, I can't really tell what it's doing. The line `table <- table` is particularly confusing. Are you just concatenating the tables?

Comment: @jclancy Sorry... that step was completely unnecessary. I've edited the code.

Comment: Did you say you were using bitexplorer.com API? I don't see any API here, I see HTML scraping.

Comment: The RStudio thing sounds like either an instability or using up all of your memory. Try checking your activity monitor and switching to R's built-in console.

Comment: What I was trying to do is skip any block for which the request to blockexplorer fails, which was happening a lot. The else statement and table <- table was definitely unnecessary

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you are absolutely right. I had been testing a different  source that does have an API and misspoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very close to 250,000 blocks on the site you mentioned (at least, 260,000 gives a 404). Curling from my connection (1 MB/s down) gives an average speed of about half a second. Try it yourself from the command line (just copy and paste) to see what you get:

`curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://blockexplorer.com/b/220000`

I'll assume your requests are about as fast as mine. Half a second times 250,000 is 125,000 seconds, or a day and a half. This is the absolute best you can get using any methods because you have to request the page.

Now, after doing an `install.packages("XML")`, I saw that running `readHTMLTable(http://blockexplorer.com/b/220000)` takes about five seconds on average. Five seconds times 250,000 is 1.25 million seconds which is about two weeks. So your estimates were correct; this is really, really slow. For reference, I'm running a 2011 MacBook Pro with a 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 and 8GB of memory (1333 MHz).

Next, table merges in R are quite slow. Assuming 100 records per table row (seems about average) you'll have 25 million rows, and some of these rows have a kilobyte of data in them. Assuming you can fit this table in memory, concatenating tables will be a problem.

The solution to these problems that I'm most familiar with is to use Python instead of R, BeautifulSoup4 instead of readHTMLTable, and Pandas to replace R's dataframe. BeautifulSoup is fast (install lxml, a parser written in C) and easy to use, and Pandas is very quick too. Its dataframe class is modeled after R's, so you probably can work with it just fine. If you need something to request URLs and return the HTML for BeautifulSoup to parse, I'd suggest Requests. It's lean and simple, and the documentation is good. All of these are `pip install`able.

If you still run into problems the only thing I can think of is to get maybe 1% of the data in memory at a time, statistically reduce it, and move on to the next 1%. If you're on a machine similar to mine, you might not have another option.

Comment: pandas are slower than data.tables in R, and it was already in 2013, check benchmarks

Comment: I share idea of jangorecki. For speed, R supersides python. Also, the above solution technique seems to not used any parallelization method of R. With parallelization in arena, the pain will be reduced much.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to parallelize the solution or refer to a good source?